# initializing variables in c#

Tags: c#

I'm a bit confused.

I have the following code:

```
public class MyClass
{
  public string DoSomething(string TheString)
  {
     int TheID;
     string TheString = "";
  }
}
```

This works fine; it compiles. However, why doesn't this work?

```
public class MyClass
{
  public string DoSomething(string TheString)
  {
     private int TheID {get;set;}
     private string TheString {get;set;}
  }
}
```

I want to make these variables private. What do I need to change?

Comment: properties cant not be part of methods. Its always part of class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Private variables are only valid at the class level:

```
public class MyClass { 
   private int TheID {get;set;} 
   private string TheString {get;set;}

   public string DoSomething(string TheString)   {

   }
  }
```

Variables defined inside a method are local in scope and they only exist inside that method.  Nothing outside the method can access them.  It makes no sense to declare a local variable as private.

Comment: Just a question : Why use private properties instead of use private members ?

Comment: @Florian, that was the example frenchie gave in his question.  Normally it would be private fields instead of private properties.

Answer (score 2):

They are scoped inside the method - you can't access them outside of it. You can think of them as being private.